# Anonymous user entering spam content as suggested edit

Tags: discussion, support

I see some anonymous user keeping on trying to introduce spam content on this [answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1171/122).

**Question:** [Should I install the Content Delivery web sites and services with Integrated Application pools?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/should-i-install-the-content-delivery-web-sites-and-services-with-integrated-app)
**Suggested Edit:** [Span Content](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1011#./1011?&_suid=138846309186307806071732121784)

I have rejected 4 times on the same answer but still anonymous user is modifying.

> **How to restrict this kind of behaviour?**

Comment: This has already been discussed in this question:
http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/259/should-we-ask-stack-exchange-to-disable-anonymous-edits-on-our-site

Comment: As an aside, I've relocked that answer for a week so we should get at least a temporary respite from the spam edits.

Answer (score 3):

We are working with Stack Exchange to attempt to figure out how to automatically block these types of spam edits. Initially we asked them to block anonymous edits on our community but it turns out this is not something they can easily do.

For now, the best thing you (and everyone else) can do is to reject these edits when they come up for review.

**Update 2014-01-24:**

We continue to have problems with anonymous spam edits to the accepted answer to [Should I install the Content Delivery web sites and services with Integrated Application pools?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/should-i-install-the-content-delivery-web-sites-and-services-with-integrated-app)

Stack Exchange has rolled out some changes to their spam detection/blocking algorithms which now identify those edits as likely spam edits but they still go into the queue for community review. As we continue to get 2 or 3 of the edits on that one question per day I have permanently locked the answer.

Later on, if the spam situation is resolved a moderator can unlock the post but for now this should block most of the spam edits we are receiving. I would not however that we have at least one other answer on another question which has also received a few anonymous spam edits so it could be the spammers will just change their target to that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: From past 5-6 days, I still keep on rejecting the spam content for the above mentioned answer. Is there any fix from stackexchange by tracking ip address or by some other way?

Comment: Siva, The good news is that Stack Exchange has been doing a better job of identifying those edits as likely spam. The bad news is we are getting 2 or 3 a day to the one answer and they still need to go through the review queue. As much as I hate to do so (because it would prevent any sort of legitimate edit to the answer) I have permanently locked the answer which has been the most frequent target of the spam edits. If the spam edit issue can be resolved a moderator can unlock the post in the future.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for locking the answer and an update.